# Chord Length Distribution in Two-Dimensional Disk(s)

Tags: integration, geometry, statistics

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^2$ be a disk of radius $R$, let $(x_1,y_1)\in A$ and $(x_2,y_2)\in A$ be points chosen randomly from a uniform distribution and let $\delta$ denote the distance between the two points. There is a distance ditribution $\Delta(\delta)$ such that $\int_a^b\Delta(\delta)d\delta$ is the probability that $a<\delta<b$. I was able to come up with the following definition of $\Delta$:

The probability of any choosing two points is equal, thus the probability can be expressed as the intgral of all sets of points separated by distance $\delta$ divided by the integral of all pairs of points:

$$\Delta(\delta)=\frac{\int_{(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\in A,\ \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}=\delta}dV}{\int_{(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\in A}dV}$$

where $dV$ is a volume differential of appropriate dimension. The denominator is simply the square of the area of A.

$$\Delta(\delta)=\frac{\int\int_{(x_1,y_1)\in A}\int_{(x_2,y_2)\in A,\ \sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}=\delta}dV}{\pi^2R^4}$$

The domain of the second integral is the union of A and a circle of radius $\delta$ centered at $(x_2,y_2)$.

$$\Delta(\delta)=\frac{\int\int_{(x_1,y_1)\in A}\int_{\theta_{min}}^{\theta_{max}}\delta\ d\theta\ dy_1\ dx_1}{\pi^2R^4}$$

This can be simplified by switching to polar coordinates, and using the Law of Cosines to find $\theta_{min}$ and $\theta_{max}$.

$$\Delta(\delta)=\frac{4\delta}{\pi R^4}\int_0^Rr\ \arccos\frac{r^2+\delta^2-R^2}{2r\delta}dr$$

This is as much as I have been able to simplify the expression. I'n not sure if the remaining integral has a closed form, but it seems as if it should.

$$$$

A slightly more complicated variation involves disjoint disks $A_1$ and $A_2$ with radii $R_1$ and $R_2$ separated by center-to-center distance $D$, and the distribution of distances between one point randomly selected from $A_1$ and another randomly selected from $A_2$. All I could get out was this mess of an integral:

$$\Delta(\delta)=2\delta\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{R_1}r\sqrt{r^2+D^2-2rD\ \cos\ \theta}\ \arccos\frac{\delta^2+r^2+D^2-R_2^2-2rD\ \cos\ \theta}{2\delta\sqrt{r^2+D^2-2rD\ \cos\ \theta}}dr\ d\theta$$

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: (http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.654.9802&rep=rep1&type=pdf) see p. 434 "Distribution for the circle" $f_{\mu}(x)$.